# Turning RGB Values Into The Basic Colors Of The Rainbow Using Python

Tags: python

Here I am again, I guess. Here is what I got so far:

```py
from PIL import Image
from tkinter import filedialog as fd
from webcolors import rgb_to_name
from pyautogui import press, typewrite, hotkey
import time

filename = fd.askopenfilename()
im = Image.open(filename, 'r')
pix_val = list(im.getdata())

def GetColor(R, G, B):
    Final = ""
    named_color = rgb_to_name((R, G, B), spec='css3') # Here
    return Final

for i in pix_val:
    press('q')
    press('t')
    typewrite('.give ' + GetColor(i[0], i[1], [2]))
    press('enter')
    time.sleep(3)
```

Now the goal is to make the script automatically turn the RGB values into simple colors like Black, Red, White, Orange, Blue, Purple, Green... you know. No intense colors like firebrick. I'm sure there is probably a way to do it by just making a simple map and if the colors match near that color then it would say it is that color. Example:

```py
XYZ = {["Red", 255, 0, 0], ["Blue", 0, 0, 255], ["Green", 0, 255, 0]...}
```

However, I want a simple little import that is already coded :/ Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: P. S. This is for a private personal project and it doesn't need done right away, although it would be nice.

Comment: The phrase "simple colors" has no meaning.  Even "basic colors of the rainbow" has no technical meaning, since all colors are in the rainbow.  The primary RGB colors are the eight combinations (0,0,0), (0,0,255), (0,255,0), (0,255,255), (255,0,0), etc., which map to black, blue, green, cyan, red, magenta, yellow, and white.  But you don't really want to print a color name for every color in an image.  That would be silly for millions of pixels.

Comment: This is for pixel art. The image is 100x100 resolution. Each pixel is run with the proper code. I will have it use "EEL" so i can copy and paste it and use it to give me the colors.

Comment: @TimRoberts It only has certain colors available to use (Minecraft)

Comment: *Each pixel is run with the proper code* -- I have no idea what that means.

Comment: @TimRoberts Meaning the part where it returns ".give " + xyz is a special code i have to run in the command prompt to give me that color.

Comment: ofc i could use the current values to you know... set it to a closer color. So firebrick would become orange...

Comment: OK, so let's restate your problem correctly.  You have a palette of valid colors.  You want to map every pixel in an image to the nearest color in that palette.  Is that correct?

Comment: yes @TimRoberts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with this is there is, in general, no good shortcut.  You have to determine the distance from each pixel to each color in the palette, and keep the smallest of those distances.

Here's one that maps to the 16 colors in the HTML4 standard set:

```
import math
from PIL import Image

colors = [
    ("black", (0, 0, 0)),
    ("silver", (192, 192, 192)),
    ("gray", (128, 128, 128)),
    ("white", (255, 255, 255)),
    ("maroon", (128, 0, 0)),
    ("red", (255, 0, 0)),
    ("purple", (128, 0, 128)),
    ("fuchsia", (255, 0, 255)),
    ("green", (0, 128, 0)),
    ("lime", (0, 255, 0)),
    ("olive", (128, 128, 0)),
    ("yellow", (255, 255, 0)),
    ("navy", (0, 0, 128)),
    ("blue", (0, 0, 255)),
    ("teal", (0, 128, 128)),
    ("aqua", (0, 255, 255))
]

def distance(a,b):
    dx = a[0]-b[0]
    dy = a[1]-b[1]
    dz = a[2]-b[2]
    return math.sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy+dz*dz)

def findclosest(pixel):
    mn = 999999
    for name,rgb in colors:
        d = distance(pixel, rgb)
        if d < mn:
            mn = d
            color = name
    return color

im = Image.open("pacmanmaze.png", 'r')
pix_val = im.getdata()

for i in pix_val:
    print(findclosest(i))
```

Comment: You can, of course, add more colors to that set.  But remember, EVERY pixel is compared to EVERY color in the palette.  The time will grow quickly if either list gets very large.